# Canvas element over div: Webcam photo capturing

Tags: jquery, webcam, html5-canvas

I want to make work the following behaviour, using jquery and the [jQuery webcam plugin](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/): After clicking a button, the `.webcam` object should be attached to some div. When I click another button, a picture is captured and drawn in a canvas, that lies on top of the div. To the user, it should seem like the image froze. Then, there should be a third button that removes the picture taken and the video stream is shown again, without the need to click `accept` in the flash opopup window for camera usage again.

I know how to place a canvas on top of the div, and it works, but as soon as the flash object is attached to the div, it seems like it comes to the front and the canvas is hidden behind it. When I call `$("div").hide()`, the canvas with the picture is shown, but `$("div").show()` then asks for permission to use the camera again.

What is the best way to solve this (possibly without hacking this jQuery plugin)?

**Edit**

One way to solve it, is setting the div's size to 1x1px while it should be hidden. This, however, is imo not the most elegant solution...

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with z-index and opacity for the elements?

Comment: I tried with z-index, and as soon as the flash object is attached to the div, it comes to the foreground. I am pretty sure that I cannot set the opacity of a running flash animation/video stream.

Comment: And have you added this to the flash object?
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](http://css.flepstudio.org/en/css-tutorials/flash-background.html) and don't forget to add the wmode parameter. It's the same principle as your streaming element becomes a background covered with a static image.

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
```

Comment: Hello Shomz, thanks for the help! Unfortunately, Adobe doesn't like it: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer10_security_changes.html#head35

Comment: Damn... sorry. Could you maybe reduce the size of the streaming window and move it somewhere else on the page?  Still not a neat solution, but a little better than going 1x1px (actually it could look nice)... Otherwise, seems like you're stuck here.

Comment: That is actually a nice idea, keeping a smaller window. Anyway, for the moment I will stick with the 1x1 px solution. It is hacky, but it works.